# Video conference in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to implement a kind of video conference on the iPhone. I know that the Faceti e API comes available sometime I can't wait for that..

Does somebody know where to start? Or some sample code would be very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**[This website listed](http://iphone-development-source-codes.blogspot.in/2012/01/sample-post.html)** some source codes of real apps, including a "**Two-way video conferencing for iPhone**"

Answer (score 0):

I would start [reading this guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html) it contains brief introduction to the video recording. 
Briefl just use UIImagePickerController to record a movie.
Encrypt it and transfer it over the network.

Comment: Hi Piotr, thank you for the answer. I knew that from the UIImagePickerController but I was wondering if there is a better/faster method to stream video from one device to another... I will check the guide again and see if there is another option. If someone knows a better solution, please post your answer.. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is I want LIVE streaming...